# Debug GAS Web App doPost to see an output of execution error

Tags: google-apps-script

The WebApp :

```
function doPost(e) {
   var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).somethingtobreakthecode()
   return "Okay"
}
```

Will fail when it receives a POST request.

Anyone, even Anonymous, can execute the WebApp.

The question is :

How can we debug a WebApp if it won't show any Logs in the logger and you cannot see the output of the execution?

I have tried BetterLog, which answers the logging part, but it requires a lot of effort if the error output is not visible.

EDIT :
List of All thing I have tried

1. BetterLog: It lets me put Logs at specific lines where I think the script will break.
2. ReqBin: It lets me see the error that this doPost will produce but to do that I have to publish a new version every time I change something.
3. DevUrl: Cannot use DevUrl with ReqBin because of lack of authorization. (Am I missing something here?)
4. StackDriver: It just shows if the execution has completed or failed.
5. I tried Logging e to pass it manually but I got [Object] object. Is it possible to get the value of (e) from doPost(e) and pass it to doPost manually from other functions?

Comment: Have you used any of the apps script loogers or is not getting to the function?https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Use a try-catch block and `console.log` the error message to have something to view in stackdriver

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of (e) from doPost(e) and pass it to doPost manually from other functions?

Comment: Have you been able to log the issue? Can you share the full code and the web app to try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the Apps Script to a GCP project by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project), re-authorize your script, make a POST reuqest to the web app and head over to https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query to see the logs output by `console.log()` statements.